# How can I avoid Index Errors?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to check if each element in the list has a difference of 1. I tried to subtract the element in the list from the previous one but it outputs an IndexError. How edit the code to remove this?

```
import sys
q = int(input().strip())
for i in range(q):
    n = int(input().strip())
    a = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a.sort()
    if a[i+1]-a[i] == 1:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Comment: When `i` is the last index in the array, you can't read from `a[i+1]` - that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[i+1]` will not work for the last element in the list because you will be going beyond the list bounds. Remember that the length of the list is not the last index in the list, since list indexing starts at 0.

I think you are overcomplicating your problem. Try using the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, but instead of starting at the first element, start at the second one. With enumerate(), the index will actually be for the element before.

```
q = [3, 5, 7, 8, 4, 5]
for i, j in enumerate(q[1:]):
    if j - q[i] == 1:
        print("Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you, I never knew about the enumerate function.

Comment: @ZarifCeaser No worries, feel free to accept the answer and upvote :)